# INotifyPropertyChanged doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1

I have a simple object (which is globally initiated in App.xaml.cs):

```
public class now_playing : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // notify
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(p + ": notify propertychanged");
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }

    // artist
    public string artist
    {
        get
        {
            return _artist;
        }
        set
        {
            _artist = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("artist");
        }
    }
    private string _artist;

    // album
    public string album
    {
        get
        {
            return _album;
        }
        set
        {
            _album = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("album");
        }
    }
    private string _album;

    // track title
    public string tracktitle
    {
        get
        {
            return _tracktitle;
        }
        set
        {
            _tracktitle = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("tracktitle");
        }
    }
    private string _tracktitle;
}
```

Whenever I change the values, the class does notify (I see the debug).
So I guess the problems lies in my XAML or the code behind.

Page code:

```
public sealed partial class nowplaying : Page
{
    // artistdata
    public string artist { get { return App.nowplaying.artist; } }
    // albumdata
    public string album { get { return App.nowplaying.album; } }
    // trackdata
    public string tracktitle { get { return App.nowplaying.tracktitle; } }

    public nowplaying()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid Margin="50">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding tracktitle}" Foreground="White" FontSize="40"/>
    <TextBlock Foreground="#dcdcdc" FontSize="20" Margin="0,50,0,0">
        <Run Text="{Binding artist}"/>
        <Run Text=" - "/>
        <Run Text="{Binding album}"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Why does the UI not update when I change values?

Stack trace:

```
Music.exe!Music.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__6(object sender = {Music.App}, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e = {Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs}) Line 50  C#

Music.exe!play_music.MessageReceivedFromBackground(object sender = null, Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayerDataReceivedEventArgs e = {Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayerDataReceivedEventArgs}) Line 57 C#
```

UPDATE: problem solved! I had to use a dispatcher when calling the propertychanged event:

```
CoreDispatcher dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    });
}
```

Comment: Side note: You should check for equality befor triggering the changed events to avoid unnecessary events in case the value not actually changed...

Comment: On the side note this line:
`PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;`
Is completly useless

Comment: @Dzior: No, but he should use `handler` in the following lines...

Comment: It is a local variable, so it would not be used at all.

Comment: @Dzior: Yes it should be used in event firing logic to avoid race-conditions in multi-threaded environements.

Comment: But you don't use this handler variable in following methods, which is a bug.

Also, if you are concerning multi-thread environment you should actually lock around every access to the handler

Answer (score 2):

You "loose" the change notification in the properties in the `Page` as these properties do not have any change notifiaction.

Try using `now_playing` directly:

```
public sealed partial class nowplaying : Page
{
    public now_playing NowPlaying { get { return App.nowplaying; } }

    public nowplaying()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

and

```
<Run Text="{Binding NowPlaying.artist}"/>
```

Otherwise you need to implement `INotifiyPropertyChanged` in `nowplaying` and forward the events from `now_playing`.

Comment: I see what you're saying. But how do I foward the events? Because now I get 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' when changing the values in App.nowplaying

Comment: Can you add the stack-trace to the question?

Comment: Done, don't know if this is helpful though

Comment: True, does not give my any cluewhats wrong now, sorry. Maybe ask as a new question as the `INotifiyPropertyChanged` seems to work now...

Comment: The problem is in the XAML now, if I remove "{Binding NowPlaying.artist}" I get no errors..

Comment: The new problem seems to be WP specific and I have no experience there, hence my recommendation to a new question...

Comment: If you are interested, I solved my problem by using a dispatcher

Comment: I was thinking about suggesting that, but I was not sure if it is requried with `INotifyPropertyChanged`...

Answer (score 1):

You actually binding to artist, album and tracktitle Of `nowplaying` class which does implement INotifyPropertyChanged